# Getting a stack overflow when trying to impliment Negamax in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: ruby, recursion, artificial-intelligence

I apologize in advance if this is a re-post, but I have read other posts on the topic and I am still can't figure out what to do.  I am trying to implement Negamax in a ruby tic tac toe game and I am getting a stack overflow error on line 55.  I have read so many posts and articles on Negamax and I still can't get it to work.

This file isn't part of a larger program yet, I just wanted to pass in a board and see if it would make a move.

```
class Negamax

    attr_accessor :board, :mark, :depth, :winning_routes

    def initialize
        @board = ["X","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
        @mark = "O"
        @depth = 1
        @winning_routes = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]
    end

    def negamax(board, mark, depth)
        if winner?(mark) || isboardfull?(board)
            return game_result(mark)
        else 
            max = -1.0/0
            mark == "O" ? opponent = "X" : "O"
            available_moves.each do |space|
                board[space] = mark
                score = -negamax(board, opponent, depth + 1)
                board[space] = "#{space + 1}"
                if score > max
                    max = score
                    best_move = space if depth == 1
                    board[best_move] = mark
                end
            end
            return max
        end
    end

    def available_moves()
        board.each_index.select { |s| board[s] != "X" && board[s] != "O"}
    end

    def isboardfull?(board)
        boardtos = board.join(",")
        boardtos =~ /\d/ ? false : true
    end

    def game_result(mark)
        if winner?(mark)
            return 1
        elsif winner?(mark == "O" ? "X" : "O")
            return -1
        else 
            return 0
        end
    end

    def winner?(mark)
        result = false
        marker = mark
        winning_routes.each do |group|
            if board[group[0]] == marker && board[group[1]] == marker && board[group[2]] == marker
                result = true
            end
        end
        result
    end
end

game = Negamax.new()
game.negamax(game.board, game.mark, game.depth)
print game.board
```

Comment: No `0` nor `1` in your `@board`? And what is this `-1.0/0` initialization of `max`? No runtime error in that line?

Comment: The expression `-1.0/0 ` is an outdated, though perfectly valid way to express `-Float::INFINITY`.

Comment: The board is a set of strings 1-9 so that a tic tac toe board will have squares numbered 1-9 on the screen.  The available spaces in negamax use the index positions of the board 0-8.  I would have thought that the runtime error would be in the negamax method, I'm not sure why it is where it is.  I initialized the max as infinity because I got it from another negamax example I found.